# Why does PriorityQueue peek() return the wrong maximum value?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm using `PriorityQueue` to get the maximum integer, but I could not figure out why the first method returns the correct maximum integer but the second method doesn't. Second method tries to update the target item's big number; but when I tried `peek()` method after update method is called, it still prints out the older maximum number instead of the new one after update.

Here is my code:

```
void add(String name, int number) {
    Item item = new Item(name, number, allItems.size());
    allItems.add(item);
    hashMap.put(name, item);
}

void update(String name, int number) {
    Item item = hashMap.get(name);

    // EDITED: 
    allItems.remove(item);

    item.setNumber(item.getNumber() + number);
    allItems.add(item);
    hashMap.put(name, item);    
}
```

EDITED: It seems like it only works if I removed the target item from allItems(Refer to EDITED in update method). Why is this so?

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item>{
        private String name;
        private int number;
        private int arrived;

        public Item(String name, int number, int arrived) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
            this.arrived = arrived;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Item o) {

            int x = this.getNumber();
            int y = o.getNumber();

            if (y > x) return 1;
            if (y < x) return -1;


            if (this.arrived > o.arrived) return 1;
            if (this.arrived < o.arrived) return -1;

            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You talk about two methods returning something, but you show us two void methods. You  do not give us the type of the collections (even if I can guess it) and do not show us the context of your two methods being called

Comment: there is no priority queue or call to `peek` in your code. Can you show a complete code sample that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Most likely, your implementation of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is incorrect.

Your `Comparable` implementation is what `PriorityQueue` uses to know how to sort the items based on the value of a field. You must implement `Comparable` in **DECREASING** order. You want it to return `-1` if the *other* item is bigger, and return `1` if *this* item is bigger; in your code you are doing the opposite. In other words, make sure your `Item` class definition looks like this:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
  private int number;
  private int arrived;

  // the rest of your code

  public int compareTo(Item other) {
    int numberCompare = Integer.compare(other.number, this.number);
    if (numberCompare == 0) {
      return Integer.compare(other.arrived, this.arrived);
    } else {
      return numberCompare;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use [`PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)) if you don't want to change the class definition of `Item`.

According to the [Javadoc for `PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered **according to their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**, or by a `Comparator` provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit `null` elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in `ClassCastException`).

Comment: If Item isn't comparable the code will throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my Comparable implementation for your reference :)